# Is that possible to ignore one of the remote repository in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have two remote repos: azure and github.

```
azure   git@ssh.dev.azure.com/prj/...(fetch)
azure   git@ssh.dev.azure.com/prj/... (push)
origin  https://github.com/prj/prj.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/prj/prj.git (push)
```

Can I ignore one of them when I work with git through IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what do you mean exactly by "Ignore one of them"?

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov, sure.
For example, when I tried to fetch something from the origin repo - the IDEA forced me to log in to 1) github 2) azure.  In my case I want that IDEA ignore the second repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest solution would be to remove the remote from the repo.

Got to `Git > Manage Remotes` and simple remove the one that points to azure. Same way you can add it later if you need it again.

Alternativ:
Open the terminal tab and run `git fetch azure`. That way only the one remote is fetched.

Answer (score 1):

For now the only option to control fetch/Pull against particular repository is to remove a remote repository from "Manage remotes" as [@Chris mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68349996/12360005)

There are similar requests, please feel free to vote:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77502

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89709